# Confusing sentences

Tags: grammar, sentence-patterns

Are these sentences grammatically correct and have the same meaning? It would be better if I get the explanations of which are right or wrong.

1. I don't want to see any more posts **which are submitted** claiming that Rahim is a thief.
2. I don't want to see any more posts **being submitted** claiming that Rahim is a thief.
3. I don't want to see any more posts **to be submitted** claming that Rahim is a thief.
4. I don't want to see any more posts **which are being submitted** claiming that Rahim is a thief.
5. I don't want any more posts which **are being submitted** claiming that Rahim is a thief.
6. I don't want any more posts **being submitted** claiming that Rahim is a thief.
7. I don't want any more posts **to be submitted** claming that Rahim is a thief.

Comment: 2, 6 and 7 express what I think you are trying to say (asking people not to submit such posts). 1 and 4 say that the posts are being submitted but you want to avoid seeing them. 3 and 5 are ungrammatical.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kate 

Comment: Kate, would you mind explaining to me why 3 and 5 are ungrammatical, please?

Comment: Because _see something_ **to be** _submitted_ is not a valid construction; it has to be _see it_ **being** _submitted_. Similarly, we say _I don't want posts to be submitted_ (meaning _I don't want anyone to submit posts_). _Posts which are being submitted_ is a phrase identifying a particular group of posts. You could say "I don't want any more posts like those which are being submitted..."

Comment: Kate is this sentence correct? and could you please tell me what it means: I don't want to see any more posts submitted which claim that Rahim is a thief.

Comment: It's similar to your sentence (2), and it implies a request not to submit any more posts of that kind.

Comment: Thanks Kate 